# Como mudar o id de minha aplicação IONIC para adicionar no Google Play Console?

Tags: ionic, google-play

Estou tentando publicar meu aplicativo no Google Play Console, mas ao adicionar o SDK aparece a seguinte mensagem.

> Use um nome de pacote diferente. "io.ionic.starter" já existe no Google Play.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém em meu arquivo config.xml O meu id está assim io.GuiaCorretor.starter

Minha dúvida é se eu consigo alterar isso sem prejudicar tudo que eu fiz até agora, como o keytool e gerar o apk com a licença...

Comment: Resolvi gerando o apk novamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você já alterou o **config.xml** o próximo passo é remover e adicionar a plataforma de destino no promp de comando através dos comandos a seguir:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

Em seguida adicione novamente

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Ao término execute o procedimento de build

```
ionic cordova build android --release --prod
```

assine o apk com o jarsigner.exe e compacte o apk com o zipalign.exe

Boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado Felipe, eu já tinha resolvido o problema mas sua resposta foi bem clara!